# Developing a really simple browser extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I'm looking  to developing a browser extension.

This extension once installed will tell the browser to include a javascript file on all page loads from a list of specific domains.

This type of extension is called "Content Scripts" by Google Chrome.

From what I read, to create this type of extensions for Chrome you simply put this code in 
"Manifest" File

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Once the extension is installed jquery.js and myscripts.js will be included on every page load of google.com

This approach to extension development adopted by Chrome seems really easy.

My question is how difficult would it be to replicate this type of extension for the other major browsers?

Comment: For other major browsers like? Firefox has its own mechanism with plugins. Safari its own. I'd say, try greasemonkey, an extension which works on most major browsers, and look into trying content scripts with Greasemonkey.

Comment: [Crossrider](http://crossrider.com) can help you with that with their cross browser extensions development framework. (you can quickly get started with javascript and the online IDE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox itself doesn't provide a simple way to load content scripts. However, the [GreaseMonkey add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/greasemonkey/) does and there is a large collection of example scripts to choose from on http://userscripts.org/. Add to this that GreaseMonkey scripts can be [compiled into a "real" extension](http://arantius.com/misc/greasemonkey/script-compiler) that no longer needs GreaseMonkey, and they can be installed in Chrome as well (without needing an extension).

Another possibility for Firefox is using the [Add-on Builder or SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder) and the [page-mod module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/packages/addon-kit/docs/page-mod.html). Something like this should work:

```
var pageMod = require("page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: ["http://www.google.com/*"],
  contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery.js"), data.url("myscript.js")]
});
```

With the Add-on Builder it should be fairly easy to turn this code into an actual extension. I have no experience with the Add-on SDK however and so I cannot offer you any additional help.

Comment: I heard about greasemonkey and user scripts. But because of the simple nature of my extension. I wanted to avoid greasemonkey all-together. However I did not know about this real extension option on top of greasemonkey.

Comment: So for Chrome I should create a manifest file with the code above. For Firefox compile a real extension on top of greasemonkey. What about the dreaded IE?

Comment: for firefox you don't need to compile anything.. it is written in xul and zipped into a xpi container file (just create a zip and rename it to xpi ;)

Comment: @Walialu: It helps when you know what you are replying to. I am talking about user scripts and zipping them up is certainly not sufficient to turn them into real extensions.

Comment: @jamjam: I edited my reply to add an example based on the Add-on SDK, this might be a better way than the ancient GreaseMonkey compiler - and it is more similar to what you do in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Kango Framework](http://kangoextensions.com). This is a cross-browser extensions framework. You can develop extensions for all major browsers working with single source code. Supports IE, Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari.